# jqGrid dependable selects

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I try to implement dependable selects. As example I took this [resource](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/dynamically-populate-select-dropdown/page-2/)

My implementation is [here](http://www.babiychuk.com/demo/de/md/index/sys_mdcolumn)

The select lists could be found in "Add new record". What is wrong there?

Comment: Currently your link is not work. Another links like http://www.babiychuk.com/demo/de/ajax/MdColumnGetTableNames?sel=1 also don't work.

Comment: @Oleg: The link is working, but not as http-call. You can not call this via browser, it is XMLHttpRequest, you can see in firebug that this call returns valid option-elements.

Comment: I have seen accidentally that you asked already 19 questions, received 25 answers and you used votes only 5 times. I suppose you don't know an important rule of stackoverflow.com. Under http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask you can read the following: "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer." If you vote up only 5 times, that it means that at least 20 answers on your questions were unhelpful for you. Is it so? I want that you just know about this.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for advice, I revisited all my questions and voted for some answers. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](http://www.babiychuk.com/demo/de/ajax/MdColumnGetTableNames??country=md_camera) (why you use '?' at the end of the url?) you will see

```
[]<option value="">Choose an option..</option><option value="md_assignment">Assignment</option><option value="md_camera">Camera</option><option value="md_film">Film</option><option value="md_film_condition">Film_condition</option><option value="md_filmformat">Filmformat</option><option value="md_filmtype">Filmtype</option><option value="md_framemaker">Framemaker</option><option value="md_lab">Lab</option><option value="md_lens">Lens</option><option value="md_owner">Owner</option><option value="md_paper">Paper</option><option value="md_scanner">Scanner</option>
```

The first `[]` characters cam make problems.

Moreover I don't understand why you need PHP session id to have the page and all HTTP GET URLs working.

**UPDATED:** I don't use PHP myself, so I can give you no advices why you has `[]` at the beginning of your server response, but it is empty `JSON` array. The corresponding response contain `Content-Type: application/json` in the HTML header and the code

```
$.get(getSelectFilterUrl, function(data) {
    var res = $(data).html();
    $('select#column').html(res);
});
```

try automatically interpret the data as JSON data. You receive an error and the 'success' function will not work. You can verify this if you replace `$.get` with `$.ajax` having `success` and `error` event handler. jqGrid use `complete` event handler instead of `success` and `error`. In the `complete` handle no data conversion will be made. It is why you have no problem with the first select.

The usage of `$.ajax` with `complete` event handler could be a workaround for you, but I strictly recommend you to examine your server code, remove `Content-Type: application/json` for the corresponding server response and fix the problem with `[]` characters.

Comment: @Oleg: Firstly I did not pay so much attention to square brackets there, as first select is rendered also with these brackets and the select works perfect. But you are right, there is no reason for the bracket. I tryed to find out why there are brackets, but unfortunately, no idea. On server-side I work with Zend and   `$ajaxContext = $helper->getHelper('AjaxContext'); $ajaxContext->initContext('json');` And then I build up my string with select element and then echo $mystring. Why there are brackets is the question. Google could not help too.

Comment: @Oleg: do you have a full index of jqgrid-demos you made? It might help many people and reduce the number of questions here or might give new ideas how to improve their applications.

Comment: @Anatoliy: I updated my answer. About the index of different demos I find it a good idea. I thought about this already. Probably in the close future I'll find time to do this. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Oleg: ad PHP Session ID - I do not understand what is the reason to talk about PHP Session ID? PHP Session is empty on jqGrid-calls. What is the connection between session and the mentioned problem?

Comment: @Anatoliy: Because urls like http://www.babiychuk.com/demo/de/ajax/MdColumnGetTableNames?sel=1 opened in web browser returns "500 Internal Server Error" and the same HTTP requests having something like `Cookie: PHPSESSID=7f728533ea22d873383afbb5e36e4413` in the headers works fine it means that your server implementation of `MdColumnGetTableNames` ***require** PHP session. See http://www.ragepank.com/articles/26/disable-phpsessid/ for example about the problem.

Comment: @Anatoliy: As I write before you should change `Content-Type: application/json` to `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. Verify whether you use `header` statement and modify it from JSON to HTML.

Comment: @Anatoliy: The usage of `$ajaxContext->initContext('json');` for the action which return HTML fragment with `<select>` statement is wrong.

Comment: @Anatoliy: Do you tried with `initContext('xml')`? The `<select>` element with `<option>` children can be seen as correct XML.